# Transformer Working Principle

Tags: voltage, power, current, transformer

What will happen if voltage sources are connected to both sides of the transformer?

In case they are different phases and when they are in same phase.

1. How will the magnetizing current be?
2. How will the flux in core behave?
3. Will it be different then the normal case?

The above question was asked in an interview. I got confused and was not to able to able to answer. Please help me with this problem.

EDIT1: This question was asked for a practical transformer.

Comment: Please use the tool, edit your question and provide a schematic. Thanks

Comment: Ideal case is not physical. In non-ideal draw your transformer and sources including the internal resistance and write down the equations.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I can comfortably deal with the mathematical part. But how will the core flux behave ? Will both sources contribute to primary flux ?

Comment: @NikhilKashyap either you can deal with the mathematical part, or you don't know how the core flux behaves. So, which is it? The math *describes* the core flux. So what's your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, please check my edited question.

Comment: Use superposition?

Comment: @Chu, please explain in a flow like I did. Mathematical part is ok.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a 1:1 transformer and the applied voltages are identical and have the same phase AND, the windings have the same "dot" position, the magnetization current will be shared by both windings, each contributing half. Think of a bifilar would primary as an example: -

[image]

Should there be a turns ratio N, then, providing the applied voltage to one side has the appropriate scaling of N or 1/N, although the magnetization currents will be different in secondary and primary (due to N), the core flux will be the same.

With different phasing you get problems unless the dot notation to one winding is the reverse of the other then it's the same as above.

With no dot notation change and opposite phases you get a big problem in theory and in reality - a bigger problem than that of a short circuit on one winding. In principle the same problem occurs when you join up two batteries in parallel but get the polarity on one of them wrong. Smoke. The flux in the core will rapidly become zero because one of the windings will melt and go open circuit or a fuse/breaker will activate.

It's simple enough to use a sim tool to see what happens.

Comment: please check my edited question. Can you please explain the flow

Comment: You have added a new section to your question that is a fundamental departure from your original question. I recommend that for you to get the best answer, you return this question to what you had originally and post a new question based upon the schematic you have added. Note also that you have not defined the magnetization inductance of the transformer so your calculations will not include it. Load currents DO NOT create magnetization fluxes.

Comment: Done. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384204/transformer-with-sources-on-both-sides

Comment: @NikhilKashyap are you finished with this question and answer now? Do you have other comments to raise?