# Transformer with sources on both sides

Tags: transformer

[image]

Please explain me the results of this problem. Here both sources are supplying active and reactive power to the transformer.

So, both sources are creating core flux together ?

Till now the flow was simple for me. Like

1. Primary source supplies magnetizing current
2. Magnetizing current sets up the core flux N1I0
3. As load is connected, load current increases which creates an opposing flux N2I2 decreasing the core flux.
4. Now as the core flux decreases, E1(induced emf in primary side) decreases.
5. As E1 decreases. I1=(V1-E1)/Z1 increases. So, N1I1 increases.
6. N1I0=N1I1-N2I2. Thus, the net flux remains constant in the core.

But I am not able to understand the flow in case of 2 sources.

Comment: The diagram needs to show the magnetization inductance on one of the windings. At the moment it has none shown and this would naturally imply an infinite magnetization inductance is in parallel with one of the windings. All that your diagram shows is leakage inductance and this does not contribute theoretically to magnetization flux. See "X0" in [this diagram](http://www.electricalunits.com/Image/Transformer/EquivalentCir.png)

Comment: Use superposition.  You know the ratio of V1 and V2, so treat each winding as primary and secondary, and superimpose the results.